# Translating jQuery into Raw Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some jQuery code that I would like to change to its raw JavaScript form, and I'm having trouble finding the corresponding elements that make up this jQuery code

```
$('.rain').append('<div class="drop" id="drop'+i+'"></div>');
$('#drop'+i).css('left',dropLeft);
$('#drop'+i).css('top',dropTop);
```

I have no idea how to change it back to Javascript, and any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help. Good luck!

Comment: There's nothing unraw about the JavaScript in your question. jQuery is a **library**, not a language. What you want to do is change JavaScript code using jQuery into JavaScript code using the DOM API.

Comment: [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), [`NodeList.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach), [`Element.insertAdjacentHTML()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML), [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), [`HTMLElement.style`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

Answer (score 0):

```
const dropDiv = document.createElement('div')
dropDiv.className = 'drop'
dropDiv.id = 'drop' + i
dropDiv.style.left = dropLeft
dropDiv.style.top = dropTop
document.querySelector('.rain').appendChild(dropDiv)
```

Comment: A class selector will most likely not only match one element

Comment: @Andreas `querySelector` selects one while `querySelectorAll` selects all. So this will select one right?

Comment: @sabithpocker `.querySelector()` only returns the first matched element, `.querySelectorAll()` returns a `NodeList` with all matched elements.

Comment: Okay. So what was your original comment referring to? I'm a bit lost here.

Comment: @sabithpocker: Probably the fact that the jQuery code would append a `div` to **every** matching element; the above only appends a `div` to the *first* matching element.

Comment: it might be better to explain your answer, rather than just supply some code

Answer (score 0):

```js
const dropLeft = 5;
const dropTop = 5;
const rain = document.querySelector('.rain');
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  let drop = document.createElement('div');
  drop.setAttribute('class', 'drop');
  drop.setAttribute('id', 'drop' + i);
  let dropText = document.createTextNode(i);
  drop.style.left = (dropLeft * i * 10) + 'px';
  drop.style.top = (dropTop * i * 10) + 'px';
  drop.appendChild(dropText);
  rain.appendChild(drop);
}
```

```css
.drop{
position: absolute;
background: blue;
width: 20px;
height:20px;
border-radius: 20px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="rain"></div>
```